# How to insert randomly between two string values in a newly created column in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

When I created the table i forgot about a column, I created it after and I want to populate that column with a RANDOM string value for example between X and Y. I work in Apex Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Create a trigger on the table to populate the field with a random value between X and Y.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER randomcolupdtrigger 
BEFORE INSERT 
ON mytable 
REFERENCING NEW AS new OLD as old
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

:new.random_column := substr('XY',round(dbms_random.value(1,2)),1);

END
```

**Update :**

For a random upper case String of a length 10,

```
:new.random_column := dbms_random.string('U', 10);
```

For a random lower case String of a length 5,

```
:new.random_column := dbms_random.string('U', 5);
```

For a random alphanumeric String of a length 20,

```
:new.random_column := dbms_random.string('X', 20);
```

Please be aware that none of the above gives you the control of generating string of your choice,they are random in nature.

If you need random String of your choice from a list of Strings that has to be dealt separately as below,

```
create or replace TRIGGER randomcolupdtrigger 
BEFORE INSERT 
ON mytable 
REFERENCING NEW AS new OLD as old
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 

type array_t is varray(5) of varchar2(20);
myarray array_t := array_t('foo', 'bar', 'foo_bar','bar-foo','1-none-1');

BEGIN

:new.random_column := myarray(round(dbms_random.value(1,5)));

END;
```

Comment: That's nice, thank you, but if i need to insert a string which has more than one character?